# Highcharts custom error handler

Tags: charts, highcharts, error-handling, custom-error-handling

We are using highcharts to plot multiple charts on a single HTML page.

However one/some of the chart throw highchart error and we like to capture those error and show different error to user.
For this highcharts do provide custom error handler. But this custom error handler does not provide information about specific chart throwing that error.

Here that JS Fiddle provided by highcharts, which works fine for a chart :

```
Highcharts.error = function (code, true) {
// See 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/errors/errors.xml
// for error id's
Highcharts.charts[0].renderer
    .text('Chart error ' + code)
    .attr({
        fill: 'red',
        zIndex: 20
    })
    .add()
    .align({
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    }, null, 'plotBox');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/highcharts-error/

Any idea how can I use this custom error handler per chart? 
I'm using new Highcharts.Charts(options) to create new chart, but don't see way to specify error handler per chart.

***Additional info:*** Charts are refreshed/appended using data through APIs. User that configures chart also configures refresh interval and query to use for chart.

Comment: This is interesting.  I would expect Highcharts to have a proper error object with context.  But that doesn't appear to be the case.  I have a solution that works for errors thrown while the charts are being created. But, if it's a dynamic update, it won't help.  Would that be useful to you?

Comment: Thank you Barbara, but yes as you rightly said, this is dynamic update use-case. Charts are refreshed/appended using data through APIs. User that configures chart also configures refresh interval and query to use for chart. Anyways please share solution you have even if that not useful for this case, it might help someone else whoever visit this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handling in HighCharts does not make much sense. It would make more sense to pass the chart instance to `Highcharts.error` (like Kamil Kulig wrote) or to have an `error` event in [`chart.events`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events). Anyways
here is a solution I came up with:

Create an array of errors:

```js
var chartErrors = [];
```

Create an error handler which will push errors into the `chartErrors`. Error objects I'm making look like this: `{"chartIndex": <chart index>, "errorCode": <error code>}`. All charts are added to the `Highcharts.charts` array when they are created so we can use `Highcharts.charts.length - 1` for the `chartIndex`.

```js
Highcharts.error = function (code) {
    // See https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/errors/errors.xml
    // for error id's
    chartErrors.push({"chartIndex": Highcharts.charts.length - 1, "errorCode":code});
};
```

After initiating all charts we will have an array of errors. We can call `forEach` on this array and handle errors the way we want.

```js
chartErrors.forEach(function(c) { 
    Highcharts.charts[c.chartIndex].renderer
        .text('Chart error ' + c.errorCode)
        .attr({
            fill: 'red',
            zIndex: 20
        })
        .add()
        .align({
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        }, null, 'plotBox');
});
```

## Working example:

**Note:** *I've wrapped the code in a self invoking function to prevent leaking variables to global scope.*

```js
(function() {
var chartErrors = [];

Highcharts.error = function (code) {
  // See https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/errors/errors.xml
  // for error id's
  chartErrors.push({"chartIndex": Highcharts.charts.length - 1, "errorCode":code});
};

Highcharts.chart('container1', {

    title: {
        text: 'Demo of Highcharts error handling'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2],
        type: 'column'
    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
Highcharts.chart('container3', {

    title: {
        text: 'Demo of Highcharts error handling'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2],
        type: 'column'
    }]
});

chartErrors.forEach(function(e) { 
  Highcharts.charts[e.chartIndex].renderer
    .text('Chart error ' + e.errorCode)
    .attr({
    fill: 'red',
    zIndex: 20
  })
    .add()
    .align({
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  }, null, 'plotBox');
});
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container1" style="height: 400px"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height: 400px"></div>
<div id="container3" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts error function is not adjusted to have a chart context as an argument, because it can be executed in different contexts too.

**For example:** error number 16 occurs when Highcharts/Highstock is loaded second time in the same page. It has nothing to do with the chart, because it depends on script importing only.

**The workaround** I found requires some searching and and a little bit of coding.

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/a8nun9aL/

I found the place in the code responsible for throwing the error 10 (the one you used in your example). I overwrote this function (see this **doc page** for more information about overwriting in Highcharts: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and added a `chart` variable (from `Highcharts.Axis.prototype.setTickInterval` scope) as the third argument:

```
  if (
    axis.positiveValuesOnly &&
    !secondPass &&
    Math.min(axis.min, pick(axis.dataMin, axis.min)) <= 0
  ) { // #978
    H.error(10, 1, chart); // Can't plot negative values on log axis // MODIFIED LINE
  }
```

It should be done for all errors you want to custom handle.

Now it can be used in custom `Highcharts.error` function:

```
Highcharts.error = function(code, stop, chart) {
  // See https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/errors/errors.xml
  // for error id's
  Highcharts.charts[0].renderer
    .text('Chart error ' + code + " on chart titled: " + chart.title.textStr)

    (...)
```

You can add your own property in chart constructor options and find it in `chart.options` object.